# Unable to install htslib v1.12 with conda

Tags: conda, htslib

I could not install htslib v1.12 with conda using either commands:

```
conda install -c bioconda htslib
conda install -c bioconda/label/broken htslib
```

Using `conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 htslib` gave me htslib v1.9.

Does anyone know how to install v1.12 with conda? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c bioconda htslib=1.12`?

Comment: Note that labels are really only for advanced use cases - unless you know you need a particular label, always use the default one (e.g., `bioconda` in this case). That particular label you tried was basically a checkpoint when for when Conda Forge transitioned to a new build stack, so it only includes old builds.

Comment: Yes, I did try `htslib=1.12` but it returned "Solving envrironment: failed", which was the same error as the 2 above commands:

Comment: What about `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda htslib=1.12`? If that doesn’t work, then you need to install it in a new environment (i.e., you have something incompatible installed in the current environment).

Comment: Wow. Thanks very much! I can install htslib finally. Could you please explain the addition `-c conda-forge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directives OP reference are from Anaconda Cloud, which are generic and miss the nuances that using specialized channels often entails. Specifically, [Bioconda expects](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) the following channel prioritization:

```yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

This is the order Bioconda uses when building and testing packages. Not following this can lead to undefined behavior.

Best practice is to either set this globally - great if you primarily work with bioinformatics software - or set it in an env-specific way (i.e., use `conda config --env`).

Otherwise, to mimic this channel priority manually one would use

```bash
conda install --override-channels -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults htslib=1.12
```

but most of the time one can get away with

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda htslib=1.12
```